# Solving this JS problem using Array.prototype.filter()

Tags: javascript

I've solved the problem below by using a nested for loop, with the some() and startsWith() methods. Is there a way to solve this using filter() instead? Thanks in advance!

> Write the function detectNetwork. It should accept a string or a
>   number for its cardNumber argument, and should return the appropriate
>   network string (or undefined if there's no match), based on the
>   provided cardData.

```js
//cardData array provided by the question
var cardData = [{
  network: 'Visa', // card issuer (network)
  prefixes: ['4'], // beginning digits
  lengths: [13, 16, 19] // lengths of card numbers
}, {
  network: 'Mastercard',
  prefixes: ['51', '52', '53', '54', '55'],
  lengths: [16]
}, {
  network: 'American Express',
  prefixes: ['34', '37'],
  lengths: [15]
}, {
  network: 'Diner\'s Club',
  prefixes: ['38', '39'],
  lengths: [14]
}];

//MY SOLUTION
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
  //convert cardNumber into a String type 
  cardNumber = String(cardNumber);

  //For each network, check if one of its prefix values matches to the prefix of cardNumber. If so, check if one of its lengths matches to the length of cardNumber.
  for (let network of cardData) {
    if (network['prefixes'].some(n => cardNumber.startsWith(n))) {
      if (network['lengths'].some(n => cardNumber.length === n)) {
        return network['network'];
      }
    }
  }
  //If no match, return undefined
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take

- dots as property accessor,
- a single `if` clase with
- [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND),
- [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and
- omit the last superfluous [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

---

```
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
    cardNumber = String(cardNumber);

    for (let network of cardData) {
        if (
            network.prefixes.some(n => cardNumber.startsWith(n)) &&
            network.lengths.includes(cardNumber.length)
        ) {
            return network.network;
        }
    }
}
```

Missed the question with `filter`. This is not applicable, becuase you want a single result, not an array of `networks`.

Take [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead with a default object and return the wanted property.

```
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
    cardNumber = String(cardNumber);

    return (cardData.find({ prefixes, lengths }) => 
            prefixes.some(n => cardNumber.startsWith(n)) &&
            lengths.includes(cardNumber.length)) || {})
        .network;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While you *could* use `.filter`, since you're trying to find *one* match (and `undefined` if there are no matches), `.find` would be more appropriate:

```
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
  const cardNumberStr = String(cardNumber);
  const cardLength = cardNumberStr.length;
  const found = cardData.find(({ prefixes, lengths }) => (
    prefixes.some(prefix => cardNumberStr.startsWith(prefix)) &&
    lengths.some(length => cardLength)
  ));
  return found
    ? found.network
    : undefined;
}
```

The same code using `.filter` would be

```
function detectNetwork(cardNumber, cardData) {
  const cardNumberStr = String(cardNumber);
  const cardLength = cardNumberStr.length;
  const filteredArr = cardData.filter(({ prefixes, lengths }) => (
    prefixes.some(prefix => cardNumberStr.startsWith(prefix)) &&
    lengths.some(length => cardLength)
  ));
  return filteredArr.length
    ? filteredArr[0]
    : undefined;
}
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.